# Can we apply Pathfilter in Oozie Fs action while moving files

Tags: hadoop, automation, move, oozie

My Dir structure is as follows;

```
 |-MyDir
 |   |--subDir1
 |   |   |---file1.zip
 |   |   |---file2.zip.tmp
 |   |--subDir2
 |   |   |---file1.zip
 |   |   |---file2.zip.tmp
```

I have to move entire sub-directories along with files to another location only if it doesn't contain any file ending with extension .zip.tmp . In other words I have to ignore sub-directories containing .zip.tmp files while moving.
My workflow is as follows:

```
 <workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.2' name='EndToEndWorkflow-wf'>
 <start to='Movefiles' />

  <action name="Movefiles">
   <fs>
    <move source='${SourcePath}' target='${DestinationPath}'/>
   </fs>
   <ok to="end"/>
   <error to="fail"/>
  </action>
  <kill name="fail">
   <message>Java failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
   </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

and job.properties has following:

```
nameNode=hdfs://XXX:8020
jobTracker=XXX:8032
queueName=default
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.coord.application.path=${nameNode}/user/hdfs/MyOozieTest
SourcePath=${nameNode}/user/hdfs/Automation/*/
DestinationPath=${nameNode}/user/hdfs/MovedFlumeFiles/
```

but this doesn't ignore .zip.tmp files. Does anybody has any helpful idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem stated above. I have written java code which uses Hadoop API's. have used FileSystem.globStatus(Path,PathFilter) for filtering files and FileSysem.rename(scr,dest) functions to move files.